# Can we have an ASP.NET Core application alongside a WordPress sites?

Tags: wordpress, apache, asp.net-core

I'm working for company which we have their own Virtual server for WordPress sites and It is running.
I don't know much about servers and hosts but I know that we run apache on server for WordPress sites and use cPanel for server management.
I create an application with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Core is a cross-platform.
My question is ...
Can I run my application on this server without conflicting with other WordPress sites?
Thanks For Your Help!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you run your ASP.NET Core server on a port which is not used by another server, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mahdi, Since you are using .NET Core you can host ASP.NET Core on Linux machines with Apache. For more details take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy) article. To see how exactly to configure Apache reverse proxy take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Also bear in mind that you can run an entire WordPress Application over an ASP.NET Core Host seamlessly using [PeachPie](https://www.peachpie.io/) which is an open-source PHP language compiler and runtime for .NET and .NET Core frameworks. If you are interested in this take a look [here](https://www.codewithmukesh.com/blog/running-wordpress-on-aspnet-core/).

Comment: In my scenario, we are already running and hosting 26 WordPress sites in that server.
I'm afraid that reconfiguring Apache shutdown other WordPress sites.

Comment: @MahdiAkbari I don't think so. Just make a try.